# Simplifying unit step functions

Tags: signal-processing, dirac-delta

I'm having quite a hard time trying to simplify the following equations:

$sinc(t)\delta(t) \\ 
 u(t)u(t) $

(by u(t) I mean the unit step function)

also, the integral $ \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} cos(t)\delta(t) \, dt = 1 $ raises some questions

I'm hoping you guys can help me out!

Comment: For the integral, it is because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\delta(t)\, dt = f(0)$.

Comment: Okay so let's take a look at the first one: sinc(t)$ \delta(t)$. We know that $\delta(t) = 0$ if $t\neq 0$, so surely the answer is $0$ if $x \neq 0$. Then we only have to plug in $t=0$ in order to find out the value at $t=0$. What is the result then?

Comment: For every function $f$ continuous at $0$ one has $f(t) \, \delta(t) = f(0) \, \delta(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac Delta is only implicitely defined with these equations
$$f(t)\cdot \delta(t) = f(0)\cdot\delta(t)$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t)\mathrm{d}t = 1$$

Thus
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(t)\delta(t)\mathrm{d}t =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(0)\delta(t)\mathrm{d}t = \cos(0)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t)\mathrm{d}t = 1\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t)\mathrm{d}t = 1 \cdot 1 = 1 $$

where $\cos(0)=1$.

The step function is defined as
$$u(t) = \begin{cases} 0, &t \leq 0 \\ 1, &t \gt 0 \end{cases}$$

Thus squaring the function does not change anything ($u^2(t) = u(t)$).